# Unable to move (click and drag) table columns and adding relation in SQL Server 2014 Management Studio

Tags: sql-server

In SQL Server 2014 Management Studio:

1. Unable move (click and drag) columns(priority) in table
2. Unable to drag relation (between tables) in 'database diagram'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of the columns in a table does not have any bearing on "priority". More importantly, the ordering of the columns in a table shouldn't have any significance to your application, the database, or your queries.

IOW, there's no reason to move them around *unless* you're querying your database with `select *` and addressing the fields in the result set by ordinals (`fields[0]`,`fields[1]`, etc.).

Comment: How can i add relation between tables when (drag and drop) is locked in database diagram?

Comment: @nasr don't. Define them properly via T-SQL as foreign key constraints.